# Set every phone can use the module of android application one time

Tags: java, android

My case now is for example select item, when i select that item, the item will become colour and after i uninstall and reinstall back, the item still is that coloured. I want to know is it possible the item selected of android application still can keep with using the method android_id? I mean this method.

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Because I plan to do is every android phone can use the function one time only. Hope can understand my question. I am using android studio.

Comment: if it is online, yes you can, using android_id can really help by saving it to your server database, though from what I know is that android_id is not really super unique at all. But it is still usable with low chance to find same id. however, if it is offline, i don't think saving file will solve the problem. Because that file can be deleted anytime if I know how to handle my android phone very well. Let's check if saved shared preference can solved that problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, basically you just need external configuration file that will be saved on external folder outside your application folder. For example you can save your configuration file in sd card. Then on your startup application, always check that file